# iOS Predicate Subquery not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am banging my head on this one...  My app has the following coredata entities:

MenuItem
ContentItem

MenuItems can have many ContentItems and each ContentItem can belong in many MenuItems, so I have a many to many relationship between the two.

The relationships are:
MenuItem -->> ContentItem: menuContentItems

ContentItem -->> MenuItem: contentItemMenuItem

I am trying to use the MenuItem's title attribute for the predicate, so my selected MenuItem's title is used in the predicate.

When the user selects a MenuItem, I want to display the ContentItems related to that MenuItem.

To show the correct list of ContentItems, I tried a standard predicate like this:

```
[fetchedRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY contentItemMenuItem.title = %@", selectedMenuItem.title]];
```

No luck. I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath contentMenuItem.title not found in entity <NSSQLEntity ContentItem id=2>'
```

I also tried a subquery like this:

```
[fetchedRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(MenuItem, m$, m.title =  %@)",selectedMenuItem.menuItemTitle]];
```

Also no luck. Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(MenuItem, m$, m.title =  %@)"'
```

There has to be a way for this to work.

Comment: Are you using `NSManagedObject` subclasses to represent your Core Data entities? If so, why can you not just use the relationship property that is on your `MenuItem` object?

Comment: I am.  Would that be in the predicate?

Comment: Ugh.  This worked...

        [fetchedRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY contentItemMenu == %@",selectedMenuItem]];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just use

```
[selectedMenuItem valueForKey:@"menuContentItems"];
```

---

Out of curiosity if you ever needed to get that `SUBQUERY` working it would look like this

```
  This evaluates to a collection e.g. `contentItem.menuItems`
             |
             |              This is the predicate
             |                       |
             v                       V
SUBQUERY(menuItems, $menuItem, $menuItem.title == 'test').@count > 0
                       ^
                       |
       This is what each item will be referred as in the predicate
```

The subquery will return a collection of results so we then just ask if there are more than 0 items returned, if so then we had a match.